# onclick event on disabled <td> only works when clicking text but not when clicking other area in td( ie10, ie11 issue)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, onclick

I  have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6qc1Lbhx/2/) html code below.

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
 <tr> <th>Col</th></tr>
  <tr><td onclick="alert('1');" disabled="disabled"><label>One<br></label></td></tr>
  <tr><td onclick="alert('2');" disabled="disabled"><label>Two<br></label></td></tr>
  <tr><td onclick="alert('3');" disabled="disabled"><label><br></label></td></tr>
</table>
```

The above code works in Chrome and Microsoft Edge means it shows alert on clicking anywhere inside  td tag in all 3 tds.
But in IE10, IE11 it works only when td contains some data, like in the above code 3rd row doesn't give alert and for other tds it only works when we click on text not when clicking any other area inside td other than text.

This code in part of my large application.
I just want to know is this a known bug in IE, if yes than can anybody provide me link of that bug.
Or am I missing something in code that causes the issue. Since it is a part of large application I want add less code so that it wont affect the rest app.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your using an old design pattern.... What are you trying to achieve? Sortable columns in a table? Use a or button instead. Tables and cells are presentation elements. a and button are action elements. you should bind the action events to them.

Comment: You don't mention what can be changed and what not in the code. What IE does makes sense: you have disabled the td so no mouse actions are registered. When you remove the disabled attribute, the click also works in IE for the whole td. When this can be changed in the html (I wonder the reason of the disabled), you obviously could do it in Javascript after page load. And be a good boy and add the event handler also there ;-)

Comment: Please add some information to your question about what you *can* do. You mention in your other comment that you cant remove the disabled. Is it needed by other code or is it posible to remove it on page load by Javascript. If yes, can you add an id or class to this table so Javascript can find it? And I guess no jQuery since it is old code.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533732(v=vs.85).aspx,

> Disabled elements do not respond to mouse events

I tested your code in IE11 and it works without the `disabled` property. I thought it might have been a `td`-specific issue so I added the `onclick` to a `div` and it works as well, as long as there is no `disabled` attribute.

[Test this on IE11](https://jsfiddle.net/cc35tpqc/8/)

Comment: Looks like your answer and my comment to the question was around the same time. With the same content. Although we're still not sure if he can remove the 'disabled'. If not this answer is not complete ;-)

Comment: @msoft he shouldn't be using `disabled` on elements that don't accept that attribute to begin with. I think `data-*` attributes would be better suited for this job.

Comment: sure thing! But often someone has to work "on top of" existing code which depends on strange settings like this. I just wanted to know if that is the case here also. Not that I can think of a reason why anyone wants this in a td, but I've come across stranger things ...

Comment: @msoft I cant remove the disabled this is the issue. I know that without disabled it will work. Also as mention in question the application is large and has some old style code I cant change much code so it wont effect other parts of app

Comment: @silentprogrammer if you can't remove it from the markup directly, why not remove it with javascript? `Element.removeAttribute('disabled')`